# Why are multiples of abundant numbers also abundant numbers?

Tags: divisor-sum

I am currently working on [Project Euler Problem 23](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23) which involves [abundant numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number).
In short, abundant numbers are numbers that are less than the sum of their proper divisors.
For example, 12 has proper divisors 1,2,3,4,6. The sum 1+2+3+4+6=16 > 12, so 12 is abundant.

Though the Wikipedia article for abundant numbers says that *every multiple of an abundant number is abundant*, I don't understand why this is true.

I think that this [Quick question on abundant numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737963/quick-question-on-abundant-numbers) on MSE is the rigorous version of what I'm after but I don't understand the proof given (if it is correct or complete).

Is there a simpler/less formal way to understand why multiples of abundant numbers are abundant?

Comment: You don't want a "less formal" proof, you want a more *detailed* proof.

Answer (score 5):

$n$ is abundant if the sum of its divisors is greater than $2n$.  Think of a list of those divisors.  If you multiply $n$ by some number $k$, you can multiply each divisor in the list by $k$ and it will still divide $kn$.  The sum of this new list exceeds $2kn$.  In fact, you can now add all the divisors of $k$ except $k$ itself, so the sum is even higher.